# How to get django form wizard extra_context to show on template?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-formwizard

**EDIT:** FWIW, I am running django 1.3

I have...

```
class CreateProductWizard(FormWizard):
    def get_template(self, step):
        if step == 1:
            return 'product/form_wizard/editor.html'
        else:
            return 'product/form_wizard/wizard_%s.html' % step
    def process_step(self, request, form, step):
        if step == 1:
            self.extra_context = {'ptype': form.cleaned_data}
            return
        else:
            return
    def done(self, request, form_list):
        # now that it's all together, store it.
        return render_to_response('product/form_wizard/done.html',
            {'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and I'd like to get the self.extra_context to the template.

How do I get that on the template?

I've tried on the template:

```
{{extra_context}}
{{form.extra_context}}
{{form.extra_context.ptype}}
```

etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I ended up using on the template was:

```
{{ptype}}
```

which I had already tried.

The problem, and I'm still not sure why was that I had:

```
def process_step(self, request, form, step):
        if step == 1:
            self.extra_context = {'ptype': form.cleaned_data}
            return
        else:
            return
```

and what worked was:

```
def process_step(self, request, form, step):
        self.extra_context = {'ptype': 'hello!!',}
```

For some reason, the 'step' that is being passed to 'process_step()' is always == 0 which made my 'if step ==1:' logic fail...

After reviewing the source (django.contrib.formtools.wizard.FormWizard), one thing that looks like it could be failing on is my form is not valid. It must be valid for the step number to increment and call the process_step function. HOWEVER, the {{step}} variable is getting the right value. And I'm not doing anything crazy with the form...

So weird. But my main question is solved.

Comment: @teewuane I know this is super old now, but the problem is that step is a string. At least it is now with the `formtools.wizard` sperated from Django in version 1.9.

Comment: @thefoxrocks , Hah, I'm trying to recall what I was even working on here. But knowing that `step` is a string and not an integer would make a difference based on what my answer is :) But wouldn't python attempt to coerce `step` into an int and compare those numbers? Or am I just thinking javascript? haha.

Comment: @teewuane I think you're thinking JS. It works for me now checking for a string. It also seems peculiar that they would send a string as a step number instead of a basic integer though... I'm sure it's confused thousands of people by this point :D

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#module-django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views) i'd say that [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_context_data) is what you are after:

> Returns the template context for a step. You can overwrite this method
>   to add more data for all or some steps. This method returns a
>   dictionary containing the rendered form step.

Comment: Dang. Looks like that is for the dev version and I'm running 1.3. Everything they've added looks pretty good though!

Comment: Almost five years later I google this problem (again) and find my question on stack overflow. Your answer was the solution for me this time. Hah!